# Save spreadsheet as a csv file in given folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a spreadsheet from my root folder to be saved as a csv file in a specific given folder.

With the help of members, I was able to merge multiple CSV files into a single sheet and delete the same contents from multiple rows, now I want to save this sheet from my root folder as a CSV file in my given folder.

```
  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1niUw2-');

  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);

  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merge Sheets");

  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();


    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId());
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    var newSheet = newSpreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
for (var i=0;i<csvData.length;i++) {
        newSheet.appendRow(csvData[i]);
      }
     var data = newSheet.getDataRange();
  var values = data.getValues();
 for (var i=values.length -1; i >=1; i--){
    if (values[i][0] == "Titel"){
   newSheet.deleteRow(i+1);
      }
 }
myFolder.createFile('MERGED',newSheet,MimeType.CSV);
  } }
```

I need this edited spreadsheet file " Merged sheet " from my root folder into my given folder as a csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to merge the CSV files in one CSV file.

  - The CSV files are in a specific folder.
- You want to create the merged CSV file in the specific folder.
- When the CSV data is merged, you want to delete the rows which has `Titel` in the column "A".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

In your script, each CSV data is put to the new Spreadsheet using `appendRow()`, and then, when the value of column "A" is `Titel`, the row is deleted. In this case, I thought that the process cost might become high. So how about the following flow?

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve each CSV file from the specific folder.
2. Parse the file as the CSV data.
3. From the CSV data, delete the rows which has `Titel` in the column "A".
4. Put the CSV data to an array.
5. After all CSV files were processed from above 2 to 4, the array including the CSV data is exported as a CSV file to the specific folder.

When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('###'); // Please set the folder ID including the CSV files.

  var csvFiles = myFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
  var data = [];
  while (csvFiles.hasNext()) {
    var csvFile = csvFiles.next();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(csvFile.getId());
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()).filter(function(row) {return row[0] != "Titel"});
    Array.prototype.push.apply(data, csvData);
  }
  myFolder.createFile('MERGED', data.map(function(row) {return row.join(",")}).join("\n"), MimeType.CSV);
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to create the merged CSV data as a Spreadsheet, please put the following script to the last line of the function of `myFunction`.

  ```
  SpreadsheetApp.create("Merge Sheets").getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  ```

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

#### Pattern 1:

If you want to delete the 1st row of each CSV data, how about the following modification? Please modify my above modified script as follows.

From:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()).filter(function(row) {return row[0] != "Titel"});
```

To:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
csvData.shift();
```

or

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
if (data.length > 0) csvData.shift();
```

- Below modified script leaves only the 1st row at the 1st CSV file.

Comment: You totally understood my question according to my requirements but there is only one thing that I need is the first row not to be deleted. For example, I have 4 sheets with same 1st row so basically I need a new sheet with my 1st row reserved as it was in the sheets and then compare the rows for ```title``` and then delete the whole row. As per my bit knowledge I tried of doing it like that but it didn't worked in my favor.```var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()).filter(function(row) {return row[1] != "Titel"})```

Comment: @Agha Musa Khan Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. My modified script reflect `if (values[i][0] == "Titel"){}` of your script. But from your replying, it seems that `if (values[i][0] == "Titel"){}` doesn't achieve your goal. About this, I couldn't notice. This is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for this. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, can you provide the sample CSV files and sample output merged CSV data? By this, I would like to confirm the issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Uey3ddrZfK6SclxvUynEzpX3Jd7e_bwb  https://drive.google.com/open?id=150LDJe-KJoSwBhhFG3BjEfCwLjXognv_   Above shared links are my single sheets and this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ihq-4Bso1IzlgQK5oP-4uAx7WRKSUW-a is my required sheet. hope I'm able to explain my situation well now.

Comment: I changed it as per your editing and it worked truly according to my requirements but can you please elaborate me a bit how it's working.

Comment: @Agha Musa Khan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. The basic flow of my modified script can be seen at my answer. About the modification of "Edit" section, the 1st row of each CSV file is deleted using `shift()`. `shift()` deletes the 1st element from an array. And, when `if (data.length > 0) csvData.shift();` is used, only 1st CSV data doesn't delete the 1st row. And other CSV data delete 1st row and is merged to the array. And then, the array is converted to the CSV data, and save it as a file. If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: thank a lot for helping. It answers my question totally.

Comment: @Agha Musa Khan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.